# Eyeball tracking issues

Tags: rigging

So I'm trying to put more work into my character before the power goes out later this week, and I stumbled across another problem.  When rigging the eyes, I tried to use [this method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=107&v=eMN9Jt1fiKw).

When I parented the empties to the head bone and applied copy rotation to the eyes like in the video (the guy used a cube to represent the head bone), the eyes would no longer track to the empties I had set up as tracking objects, breaking the rig.  There's probably something about the copy rotation constraint that's overriding the track to constraint, but I'm not sure how else I can go about it.

My character has ovular pupils that I want to stay aligned with the head bone when I make my character cock his head to one side.  What happens now is that the eyes stay oriented to the world z axis and not to the direction of the head bone.

How do I fix this?

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (delete all the non-important parts): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Here:[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=swDjXRMR" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/swDjXRMR/)  I stripped out the copy rotation constraints and hid everything irrelevant and the eyes are not parented to the head bone

Comment: so your little cubes are your controllers, when I move them the sphere move as well, it seems to work fine, of course you'll need to parent your sphere and controllers to the head bone... but could you please show with several pictures where is the problem you're talking about?

Comment: So when I do parent his eye empties (which the spheres themselves are parented to) to the head bone, the eyes don't properly inherit the rotation of the head bone.  That is, they stay oriented with the world z axis as they follow the head bone's rotation.  I want them to track to the head bone's local y axis instead. I tried applying the copy rotation constraint to the geometry on his eye to fix things but it only made things worse! I can email you a couple of screenshots if you want.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it! :D Just had to mess with some of the parameters in the copy rotation after unparenting the irises. I reparented them later and everything works.

Comment: sorry I had no time to check again, but nice if you fixed it  ;)